# Is the output of a compression algorithm (for example gzip, zip, or snappy) definitely smaller than the input?

Tags: java, c++, c, compression

I have this question since I need to allocate the output buffer for the compressed data. I need to know how large the buIs the output of a compression algorithm (for example gzip, zip, or snappy) definitely smaller than the input?

Comment: Strictly speaking, no. Usually? Yes.

Comment: depend on your data : for example a random signal cannot be compressed.

Comment: If it was *always* smaller, then you would be able to apply recursive compression indefinitely...  When your file size becomes zero, then the compressed size cannot be smaller than zero, therefore the answer is "no" =)

Comment: @paddy you should add this as an answer

Answer (score 3):

For **lossy** compression algorithms it is possible for this to be the case, though not guaranteed. For **lossless** compression algorithms this is not the case - a lossless compression will always generate outputs that are *larger* than the input for some inputs. See [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle#Uses_and_applications) for reasoning why.

Comment: The identity compression algorithm (for input X, produce output X) is lossless but never produces an output larger than its input.

Comment: @Borealid While this is true very few people would consider this a "compression" algorithm in the common sense of the word. It may be a technical truth but it's a nearly useless statement.

Comment: @Borealid Clever, but not really the point here. Also, if we're gonna nitpick: the question does not say "smaller *or equal*", it says "smaller".

Comment: If we are going to nitpick, it is not [compression](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=compression&sub=Search+WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=) if the density decreases.

Answer (score 0):

there is always a fixed size associated with the "header", but for any real-life data (e.g. the length of this comment), compression will usually help.

That said, it is not "safe" to declare a post-compression buffer to be the same size as the input buffer.  It *might* be bigger.

Comment: A lot of "real-life data", such as most useful audio, image and video file formats, is already compressed (pretty well too), so compression rarely helps with those.

Comment: In real life the compression library returns to caller after filling an output buffer. That being said, it's safe to declare 1MB output buffer for gzip that is trying to compress your complete .mp3 collection.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not.

A quick example: Data with uniformly distributed non-repeating values can not be compressed without loss, and so you end up with the original data, plus the attached meta data.

Comment: "XXXXXXXXXX" is truly random, although unlikely.

Comment: Also, "random" does not necessarily mean "evenly distributed".

Comment: I think the correct way of stating this claim is that the expected value of the ratio `compressed_size:original_size` is always greater than or equal to 1, assuming (this is what you mean by "random") a uniform distribution of all possible inputs. In other words, compression is only useful because real-world inputs are not uniformly distributed.

Comment: Hah, yeah I totally to forgot to add the part about evenly distributed :)

Answer (score 0):

Compression libraries, such as zlib (for inflate/deflate used in gzip & pkzip) are more likely designed to process max N bytes from input and output max M bytes to user allocated buffer -- and signalling the caller if the library expects either new input data or new/cleared output buffer. Only rarely those libraries expect complete input and output residing in memory, but work on blocks.

Also the 'search windows' of many common algorithms are relatively small. This also limits the amount of required memory. Counter examples exists e.g. BWT used in tar.bz2.

And as other people have pointed out, the output of any lossless compression algorithm can be larger than the input, in which case most well designed compression libraries implement automatically a fallback mechanism, which just wraps an uncompressed block to a container with size information.

To summarize: many compression libraries just require a buffer from few kilobytes to few megabytes and process an input of any length with it. (Such constrains are btw included in MPEG -- in addition to the expected frame size (e.g. 128 kbps in mp3) they have specified the maximum required buffer size)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using zlib (for gzip), you might find the following interface useful: (from `zlib.h`)

```
ZEXTERN uLong ZEXPORT compressBound OF((uLong sourceLen));
/*
     compressBound() returns an upper bound on the compressed size after
   compress() or compress2() on sourceLen bytes.  It would be used before
   a compress() or compress2() call to allocate the destination buffer.
*/
```

I believe that bzip has a similar interface. The value returned will be slightly larger than sourceLen, and should only be used if the data is compressing is small enough that you can do the compression in memory. For such applications, though, it's very useful.

Note that most of the time, you won't use most of the memory allocated, so you would also want to be able to return the unused memory if you are planning to keep the compressed version in memory for any length of time.